# Length of string in String.Format()

Tags: c#, .net

It's may be I'm doing something wrong but don't know why I'm getting such issue.
I'm using `string.Format` which took around 130 parameters my code look like as below

```
string query = string.Format(@"Insert into TB_LN_CASES (
                col1, 
                col2,
                col3,
                col4,
                ...
                ...
                col129,
                col130) Values ({0},{1},{2},{3}.....{129})", 
                col1.ToString(),
                col2.ToString(),
                col3.ToString(),
                col4.ToString(),
                ...
                ...
                col130.ToString());
```

The output which I'm getting in string is like

```
Insert into TB_LN_CASES (col1, col2,col3,col4,
                    ...
                    ...col129,col130) Values (abc,efd,gr,y,t,ui,u,re,re
```

String is incomplete, don't know what is the reason behind this or is there any alternative to do this, please suggest

Is there any max length constraint for `string.Format` ?

Comment: what is such issue here?

Comment: I have the same question. Where is your issue?

Comment: You should stop coding like this. You've got a list of columns so implement a list of columns and not variables en mass.

Comment: if column one is string type then u have to use the parameter as '{0}' instead of {0} . if this is numeric type then you can leave it. Take care of data type it should work.

Comment: sorry posted incomplete question, I'm updating it @un-lucky

Comment: @QualityCatalyst could you please share something any link or code how to do it

Comment: @NazmulHasan hey I'm getting some issue ok, don't judge it with my reputation

Comment: **You are most definitely doing something wrong.**  
The thing you are doing wrong is using `string.Format` to create an insert statement, instead of using parameterized statements.  
This is a **major security hazard** since it's an open door for [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @ZoharPeled ok i'll keep it in mind, but the actual question is, is there any constrain with string.Format() . any max length constrain

Comment: There is no MaxLength issue for you with the string. You run in an issue with your database first as it won't take statement millions of characters long.

Comment: Don't keep that in mind, change your code **now.** Sql injection attacks are very powerful and immunizing your code is very easy. All you have to do is use parameters instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: btw, `string.format` already calls `ToString()` on every parameter it gets, so that's redundant.

Comment: ok @ZoharPeled will do it now

Comment: @Co.Aden: check the MSDN please (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). You are limited by the length of `string`. Again, super long statements won't be executable in your database anyway!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561020/string-format-parameters

Comment: @QualityCatalyst this is really helpful, also I'll do use parameters instead of string, thanks

Comment: @Co.Aden I have updated my answer to include the following link, hope this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561020/string-format-parameters

Comment: Be aware that contrary o what people like Zohar say there are good reasons to avoid parameters on insert statements. The main one: Insert can insert many rows.... but you are still limited to around 1000 parameters. Less than 10 lines in your example, while the insert statement could have 1000 rows in one statement or more. SQL injection is a total non issue with a little planning on the parameter processing. I am generally in favor of using parameters, but contrary to certain near religious zealot attitudes, one has to accept that there are cases it makes sense not to use them.

Comment: Step back and determine if this table needs 130 columns

Comment: @TomTom inserting multiple rows can easily be achieved with a single table valued parameter, so that's a non-issue. any other reason not to use parameters?

Comment: The argument against parameters in general is speed achieved across large datasets in loops. Depending on the source of the data, if one can rule out sql injection, then bulk inserts are vastly superior.

Comment: Yes, bulk inserts are the preferred way to insert massive amount of data to sql server, however that's clearly not relevant when taking user inputs, so I don't really consider them as an argument against parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is so totally not a string.format issue that it is not funny.

Please consider doing a little basic debugging yourself.

> Values (abc,efd,gr,y,t,ui,u,re,re

This is not valid SQL. See, string values have to be in paranthesis of some sort ('abc' instad of abc).

Simply speaking your (btw, the old string.format syntax is hard to read - learn to use $"" strings, the new syntax for formatting in .NET 6.0) generated SQL is bad and you never considered this a SQL error.

Now, for the length issue - that is no, there is no sensible limit that you would reach. There is one, but it is LONG (not sure about the string limit - 2 gigabytes RAM?). It is likely you have a serious presentation issue (as in: The string is there, you just do not see it, like in the debugger, which may limit the output length).

I would reformat that to use he new $"{paramname}" syntax - it is a LOT easier to debug once you hit 10 or 20 parameters.

Please also note: The ToString calls on all those parameters are surplus (default call anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If you are building up a SQL query, I would strongly recommend you use parameters in your query.

Here is an example:

```
string strQuery = "Insert into TB_LN_CASES (col1, ...) VALUES (@columnOneVariable, ...)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnOneVariable", "yourValue");
```

At the moment you are very vulnerable to SQL injection.

To answer your question about the limit on `String.Format()`, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561020/string-format-parameters)

Comment: ok, i'll do that but main thing is, is their any max length constrain with string.Format()

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Take a read here, might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string

Comment: Actually there is - but it will not bite you. I think you are limited to around 1 billion characters. Things get ugly way before that, though - and in terms of SQL... that would really blow anything sensible out of the water as one statement anyway.

Comment: @TomTom Thanks for the info. Am I correct in saying, the limit, for in memory objects/variables, is 2GB, as per the article I have suggested above?

Comment: I think yes. For strings (remember, 2 bytes per char) that runs around 1 billion chars. Now, I have seen SQL Statements I Would assume to be longer than what most people here see (including multi megabyte insert statements).... but from there to the string limit.... worlds of difference. Also note: for the pure string part, consider using a stringbuilder (and it's AppendFormat method) as it may be more efficient internally. Heavy string manipulation with strings generally creates a ton of garbage (though I am not sure about a single string.format).

Comment: @TomTom thanks for your input.  Do you think StringBuilder would be more efficient in this case, where the OP has mentioned 130 parameters?

Comment: Not sure. Generally the advice is to use stringbuilder instead of a lot of additions - but one "format to rule them all".... never tried. I have no real idea how string.format works internally. The source is open source, jsut never looked it up.

Comment: Me neither, something to check out later when I have a free moment. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: How is stringbuilder protecting against sql injection?

Comment: @Drew I never mentioned StringBuilder will protect against SQL Injection

Comment: I know sir. Just wanted to make it clear to the OP. Thanks for helping him

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into TB_LN_CASES (col1, col2,col3, ..) 
                        Values (@value1, @value2, @value3, ..) ";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value1", value1));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value2", value2));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value3", value3));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I will -1 this because there are good reasons not to use parameters in this - mostly that you can make a LOT of rows in one SQL insert but are limited to around 1000 parameters. Also it does work around the question and never even bothers to answer it (which is a pure sql issue).

Answer (score -2):

```
string.Format("@"Insert into TB_LN_CASES{0},{1},{2}", col0,col1);
```

Comment: what my question is, is there  any constrain with string.Format() I don't want to correct my query by any other way

Comment: Check your answer. It doesn't address the question and fails anyway as the built statement is non-SQL compliant.